# Zend prevent application from loading viewscript

Tags: zend-framework

How can I prevent an application from rendering the viewscript with any parameters.

So if I have something that is

www.mywebsite.com/myapplication/mycontroller/some/params

How can i stop it, so that no matter what comes after the controller it won't load the view script. I have been able to do this in the actions, but I want to do it for all actions.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your question. Is this a routing issues where you don't want to route past the controller level? Is this a display issue where you don't want viewscripts displayed because you are using them for some other purpose? Is this a security issue?

Comment: @RockyFord more like if the user is not logged in, I don't want to show the page.

Comment: in that case you may want to do that with [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) so that on every request your application can check for login status and redirect as required.

Comment: @RockyFord Interesting, I'll have to take a look at that. Because I'm using another script which uses zend, so I'll have to see if they implemented that. Would be nice if they did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I had to do to get it do what I want:

```
    public function preDispatch(){
        if($this->User->isValid()){
            if($this->getRequest()->getActionName() !== 'login' ){ 
                    $this->_forward('login');
            }
         }
    }

    public function loginAction(){
        $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('You must be logged in to do that!');
        $this->_flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
        $this->view->messages = $this->_flashMessenger->getMessages();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the front controller enables the ViewRenderer action helper. This helper takes care of injecting the view object into the controller, as well as automatically rendering views. You may disable it within your action controller via one of the following methods:

```
class FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init()
    {
        // Local to this controller only; affects all actions,
        // as loaded in init:
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

        // Globally:
        $this->_helper->removeHelper('viewRenderer');

        // Also globally, but would need to be in conjunction with the
        // local version in order to propagate for this controller:
        Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
            ->setParam('noViewRenderer', true);
    }
}
```

ref: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html

Comment: I'll give that a shot, I did that, but I just did setNoRender without removing the helper.

Comment: To do this globally, you can use Eswar's `init()` function inside an abstract controller class which all of your other controllers extend.  I've done this for making JSON-based API's for example.